# how to add a DOM model in a HTML structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a DOM structure in a html page. Like one ROW having two input fields, buttons , dropdowns etc. How can I create that structure without using string append. like `"<li> <p>etc etc</p> <button class="etc"></button> etcetc </li>"`.
I know how to create single element like

```
$( "<div></div>" )
  .addClass( "my-div" )
  .on({
    touchstart: function( event ) {
      // Do something
    }
  })
    .appendTo( "body" );
```

But how can I create a DOM structure?

Comment: Do stuff like the `.appendTo()` code over and over again?

Comment: Use a templating engine.

Comment: It's basically repetition (as suggested by Pointy, above) or using an HTML string; pick one. In some browsers you could implement the [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested `append`s like shown below.

```
$('<li>')
    .append(
        $('<p>')
            .text('etc etc')
            .append(AGAIN-SOMETHING-ELSE)
    )
    .append(
        $('<button>')
            .addClass("etc")
            .text('etcetc')
    )
    .appendTo('body');
```